What would be the time equivalent to the word "geographic"?
I am writing an essay, and want to say that two novels are similar despite being written in different countries and decades. The line is:
"...the two novels, which both make similar critiques of patriarchal oppression despite their different geographic and ___ contexts". (I might change geographic to cultural, but you get the gist.)
I am thinking that "temporal" might be the closest answer, but I wonder if that adequately gets across the meaning of "written in different decades" or if there is a more specific word? Thank you in advance.

Have you considered "historical"?

@MetaEd Would that still work when one novel is fairly contemporary (2010s)? To me, "historical" feels like I would be talking about two works from some time in the past.

I'd use two words: 'temporal setting'. Or three: 'the period concerned'.

@Geographic3745 I am with MetaEd:  "historical" works.  Note that history is always ongoing.  Right now, we are living in a particular historical context.
History doesn't have to mean "a long time ago".  "Temporal" also works, but it feels a little stilted to my ear.  Replacing both "geographic" and [whatever] with "cultural" seems to dull the meaning some---it is less specific, as having both differing geographic and historic contexts implies different cultural contexts, but not the reverse.

It might. Or you could consider "generational" (as in gen X, gen Y, etc); or more generally "social context"

Slight rephrase could be "geographies and eras", if you don't need the word contexts.

@jimm101 yes, that is one of the problems here. The sentence has a great deal of the smell of the lamp about it. We normally use the paired phrase place and time. So something like ... despite having been set in different places and times.

You could leave out both adjectives: "despite their different contexts." The essay will no doubt explore those differences.

I think that "temporal" is the real parallel to "geographic."
But if you want to switch "geographic" to "cultural," you don't need to add in a phrase that specifies anything about time, because anyone who studies cultures is going to be well aware that cultures are always set in a time.

Cultural contexts could be at the same time. For instance, we might use it to distinguish between authoritarian and democratic cultures in the 21st century.
